# pigeonhole principle question 40 participants in an art workshop

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle

There are 40 participants in an art workshop. Each one of them signed up for one or more of the following courses: handicraft, ceramics and Chinese paintings. One of the combinations of courses must have at least n participants. Find the largest possible value of n.

Anyone know how to do this? It is not for homework or anything I just wanna know the way to do it.

Comment: What does "the combinations of courses" mean?  Can a single course be a "combination"?

Comment: List the possible combinations of courses (everyone does something) - how many are there? Distribute the people as evenly as possible between combinations to get the lowest possible maximum.

Answer (score 2):

There must be at least 14 participants signed up for one of the three classes (by the pigeonhole principle), and this is the best possible $n$ if one means simply that some (single) combination of a class must attract at least $n$ participants.

However if instead we mean to count participants whose entire signup selections agree, then the number $n$ will come down.  There are seven possible (nonempty) selections of classes (as computed by $2^3 - 1$, discarding the empty subset of no classes), and distributing the 40 participants as evenly as possible across these combinations gives as few as $n=6$ in the largest number of participants.  One again argues by pigeonhole principle that $n=6$ will not be improved upon (if only 5 or fewer signed up for any one of the seven combinations, we'd have at most 35 participants).